# Mysql error 1064 in Mysql 5.1- unable execute successfully

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am trying to write trigger in Mysql (5.1), but getting following error, please help.

The error is:

> SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '' at line 5.

Purpose for writing trigger:

I am writing application where I am assigning users, and I want to store unassigned `usercount` to field `cluster_count` in `IX_branchdetails` table.After updating the base table.

trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE  TRIGGER upd_trg AFTER
UPDATE ON DBNAME.BASETABLE
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
DECLARE m_branchcode INTEGER;
DECLARE cnt INTEGER;
DECLARE cursor_branch CURSOR FOR
SELECT DISTINCT branchcode
FROM ix_branchdetails;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
open cursor_branch;
my_loop: loop
set done = false;
fetch cursor_branch into m_branchcode;
if done then
leave my_loop;
end if;
select count(1) into cnt from (select count(1) from BASETABLE  Where IX_BRANCHCODE = m_branchcode) as temp;
update DBANAME.ix_branchdetails set DBANAME.ix_branchdetails.cluster_count = cnt where  DBANAME.ix_branchdetails.BRANCHCODE = m_branchcode;
end loop my_loop;
close cursor_branch;
END $$ 
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Add `DELIMITER $$;` in the start and the same delimiter at the end.

Comment: Corrected my Trigger block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a declare for the `done` variable:

```
DECLARE done TINYINT DEFAULT FALSE;
```

The semicolon (;) is the default delimiter for MySQL statements. To get a procedure/function/trigger defined, we normally see the statement delimiter changed to a string that doesn't appear in the statement:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE ...

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

If the delimiter is not changed from the semicolon, then when MySQL encounters the first semicolon in your procedure/function/trigger, it sees that as the end of the statement, which is not what you want.  You want MySQL to see the entire block of code as a single statement.

Comment: Thanks Spencer,nice description.